# How can I run R script with Jython?

Tags: r, user-interface, jython

I want to run my R code through Jython. I have not used Jython before. Can anyone of you please tell me how can I do? Can rJython help me to do so?

Comment: Jython linkes Java to python. Why do you want to use it? Are you restricted to use a JVM for R?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to develop a GUI using Jython. Jython in background works with R to fetch the output. So, I want to source my R code inside Jython.